# No matching client found for package name '', but google-services.json is present in the app directory

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm getting a little desperate here. My React-Native app has two app folders and both these folders contain a google-services.json file with the correct structure and a "package_name" is definitely present and has the correct value. The file looks like:

```
{
  "project_info": {
  "project_number": "123456789123",
  "firebase_url": "https://myproject.firebaseio.com",
  "project_id": "my-project",
  "storage_bucket": "my-project.appspot.com"
},
"client": [
  {
    "client_info": {
      "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:878210515221:android:64cb9c9ba170c841",
      "android_client_info": {
        "package_name": "com.mycompany.appstore.myproject"
      }
    },
    "oauth_client": [
      {
        "client_id": "123456789123-ipr3gfqml3oaajpk1lsq6gvf81mebkcm.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "client_type": 3
      }
    ],
    "api_key": [
      {
        "current_key": "mykey-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
      }
    ],
    "services": {
      "analytics_service": {
        "status": 1
      },
      "appinvite_service": {
        "status": 1,
        "other_platform_oauth_client": []
      },
      "ads_service": {
        "status": 2
      }
    }
  }
],
"configuration_version": "1"
```

}

Both google-services.json files have the same content (I've replaced some values with dummy text in this example), but the `react-native run-android` command keeps giving me the `No matching client found for package name ''` warning, and it doesn't even mention a package_name but says it's an empty string.

All solutions on the internet are "Put a google-services.json" file in your app folder. That clearly doesn't help me in this case. Any idea what the issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have multiple Flavor you need to create multiple client on firebase portal for same application

for example (in android)

```
productFlavors {
        prod {
            applicationId "com.xyz.abc"
            dimension "tier"
        }
        apiary {
            applicationId "com.xyz.abc.apiary"
            dimension "tier"
        }
        local {
            applicationId "com.xyz.abc.local"

            dimension "tier"
        }

    }
```

otherwise check your package name in app and google-services.json